# Comment proofs without qed symbol

Tags: comments, proof-package

I am using the comment package in order to hide all proofs when needed. Whenever I comment all proofs, the \qed symbol remains, which I would want to avoid. I could remove the qed symbol altogether but I would rather want to avoid that as I still want it to appear when I do not comment out proofs.
It feels like this is due to a conflict between thmbox and the comment package. Here is a minimal example:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% -*- coding: UTF-8; -*-
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmbox}
\usepackage{comment}

\excludecomment{proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Test. 
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

When \excludecomment{proof} is active, the qed symbol remains. This does not happen when the package thmbox is removed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code (with dummy text) resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Thank you for making me clarify my problem. I have edited the message.

Comment: How about commenting out `\usepackage{thmbox}`? The proof environment of `amsthm` does not have this issue.

Comment: I really do need that package, unfortunately...

Comment: @thegain, in that case, just add `\renewenvironment{proof}{}{}` before `\excludecomment{proof}`

Comment: It does the trick indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

A quick hack:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmbox}
\usepackage{comment}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\renewenvironment{proof}{}{}.  %<----
\excludecomment{proof}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
For any nonnegative integer $n$, we have
\[
\sum_{i=0}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
\]
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
We prove the theorem by induction on $n\geq 0\ldots
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed, if I manually comment each proof with comment surrounding proof, this does the job. Problem is I want to use comment all proofs, which makes this a bit cumbersome (note my edit which has clarified the problem with a minimal example).
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In the manual of the [package comment](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment) I find the statement that you define a new environment either via `\includecomment` or via `\excludecomment`.

In the manual of the [package comment](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment) I do not find any statement regarding redefining/overriding environments that are already defined.

If you explicitly use any of the directivess `\includecomment{proof}`/`\excludecomment{proof}`, then the definition of the begin-part of an already defined `proof`-environment, but not the definition of the  end-part of an already defined `proof`-environment, is silently overridden.

E.g., look at the subtle differences with none of these directives being used:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\newenvironment{proof}{Proof:}{This is the end.}
%\includecomment{proof}
%\excludecomment{proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This is a proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

, yielding

[image]

, versus the `\includecomment`-directive being used:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\newenvironment{proof}{Proof:}{This is the end.}
\includecomment{proof}
%\excludecomment{proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This is a proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

, yielding

[image]

, where -- due to overriding the begin-part of the former definition of the `proof`-environment -- the phrase "Proof:" is gone but both the characters forming the environment-body and the phrase "This is the end.", the latter coming from the end-part of the former definition of the `proof`-environment, are not gone,

, versus the `\excludecomment`-directive being used:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\newenvironment{proof}{Proof:}{This is the end.}
%\includecomment{proof}
\excludecomment{proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This is a proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

, yielding

[image]

, where everything but the phrase "This is the end.", coming from the end-part of the former definition of the `proof`-environment, is gone.

**Therefore, although you don't get error-messages, I think the commands `\includecomment` and  `\excludecomment` are not intended for overriding environments that are already defined.**

If you still want to do that, I suggest something like the following, where enabling `\includecomment{proof}` gives the same result as if neither `\includecomment{proof}` nor `\excludecomment{proof}` were enabled:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmbox}
\usepackage{comment}

\begingroup
\renewenvironment{proof}{}{}%
\def\SecondThirdFirst#1#2#3{#2{#3}#1}
\def\proofredefiner{\renewenvironment{proof}{}{}\excludecomment{proof}}%
%%%% Here you can toggle \includecomment / \excludecomment:%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\includecomment{proof}%
\excludecomment{proof}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{proof}
\catcode`\%=9\relax
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
\SecondThirdFirst{\def\proofredefiner{}}%\relax\relax
\end{proof}
\expandafter\endgroup\proofredefiner

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
This is a proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `\excludecomment`-directive disabled you get -- no matter if the `\includecomment`-directive is enabled or not:

[image]